# Make a mongodb request in a middleware

Tags: nestjs

I would like to make a find request in my db but in my middleware, so I did naturally as in my service and added a constructor for my model but I have this error:

```
(node:821) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AccountMiddleware (?). Please make sure that the argument AccountModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If AccountModel is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If AccountModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AccountModel */ ]
  })
```

If I remove the constructor I don't get any error so I don't understand how I can declare my model
Here my actual middleware code:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { IAccount } from './interfaces/account.interface';

@Injectable()
export class AccountMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Account') private readonly accountModel: Model<IAccount>) {}

    async use(req: any, res: any, next: () => void) {

        next();
    }
}
```

thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just as the error says, you need to have access to the `Account` model in your `AppModule` because that's where you're binding the middleware. To make sure you have access to this, you need to either import `MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Account', schema: AccountSchema }])` or you need to import a module that already imports the above `MongooseModule` **and** exports it

Comment: I've already done this since I use this same builder in my service, that's why I don't understand why I have this error

I have that on my account.module:  https://prnt.sc/13etv98

Comment: But your `AccountModule` doesn't export the `MongooseModule`, and the error comes from the `AppModule` not the `AccountModule`